# Correct MariaDB Syntax for SQL Replace Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sqlanywhere

After trying to determine why my SQL statement was returning an error in the Node code I am refactoring to connect to MariaDB rather than via SQL Anywhere, I have narrowed it down to the `REPLACE` statement we use to compute how many records to process, and how many to skip.

My initial test SQL SELECT statement looks like this:

`SELECT customer_name FROM ar.customers`

We then use a `REPLACE` statement to, as I say, determine how many records to process, and how many to skip. When we were using SQL Anywhere that looked like this:

```
const sql = this.query.replace(/SELECT/i, `SELECT TOP ${recordsPerRun} START AT ${recordsProcessed + 1}`);
```

That syntax needs to change because MariaDB uses "LIMIT" instead of "TOP". And from my understanding, the first parameter will be the number of records to skip, and the second one how many to return.

So, in my case, it'd be something like:

`LIMIT ${recordsProcessed}, ${recordsPerRun}`

However, I can't quite get the full syntax right. How can I write this `REPLACE` statement in a way that will work with my initial test SQL SELECT statement from above? This seems tricky to do since in MariaDB `LIMIT` now goes at the end of the query, not at the beginning, like `TOP` did for MySQL.

Comment: Note that `OFFSET` takes longer as it grows -- because it takes time to skip over those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` goes at the end, so there's nothing to replace, just concatenate it:

```
const sql = this.query + ` LIMIT ${recordsProcessed}, ${recordsPerRun}`;
```

or combine it into the template:

```
const sql = `${this.query} LIMIT ${recordsProcessed}, ${recordsPerRun}`;
```

Comment: Yes, of course, that makes sense. Many thanks, @Barmar!